# Swift - Put variable in switch case?

Tags: variables, swift, switch-statement, case

I'm trying to put a variable into a switch case but it won't let me.
I have this right now.

```
var shade = NSInteger()
```

I'm trying to put the variable shade instead of 50

```
func rPercent() ->Double{
   return Double(arc4random() % 100)
}
let randGen = rPercent()
switch randGen{
case 0..<50:
functhisthing
break
case 50..<100:
functhisone
break
default:
break
}
```

Comment: I tried your code and it works fine, I just replaced functhisone with println(). What is functhisone? you don't need break in swift switch, you just need break in empty case, in your example you just need break keyword after default.

Comment: It seems it needed to be var shade: Double?, thanks for the info about not needing break at the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the rPercent returns a Double, so you could not compare with an Integer:

Try:

```
func rPercent() ->Double{
    return Double(arc4random() % 100)
}

var shade:Double = 50

let randGen = rPercent()
switch randGen{
case 0..<shade:
   println("1")
break
case shade ..< 100:
    println("2")
break
default:
break
}
```